# Get a message's ts value from /archives link

Tags: slack, slack-api

Slack has a *Copy link* feature, which copies a deep link to an individual chat message to the clipboard:

[image]

Here's an example of such a deep link (obfuscated):

`https://myworkspace.slack.com/archives/CqwertGU/p1234567898000159`

What I'd like to do is, get the details of that message from the Slack API given that link.

The first string after `/archives/` is the channel's ID. I'm not quite clear about that second string though:

According to [Slack's API documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history),

> `channels.history` can also be used to pluck a single message from the
>   archive.
>
> You'll need a message's `ts` value, uniquely identifying it within a
>   channel. You'll also need that channel's ID.

So, what I've found is that the `p1234567898000159` value in the link above is *almost* the message's `ts` value, but not quite (the Slack API won't accept it): the leading `p` needs to be removed, also there has to be a `.` inserted after the 10th digit: `1234567898.000159`

Putting all this together into an API request...

`https://slack.com/api/channels.history?latest=1234567898.000159&channel=CqwertGU&count=1&pretty=1&token=mytoken123&inclusive=true`

... I'm getting a response with all the message details, exactly what I need.

My question is: am I doing this right? Do I really need to craft the message's `ts` value from the URL parameter this way, or is there a better, more robust, officially supported way?

Comment: No, that is obviously not the "supported" way of retrieving the TS for a message. You do that by browsing through `channels.history` or using `search.messages` with your app. But what is it you want to do exactly? You did not say

Comment: My use case is: user copies link to clipboard and pastes it into my app, another chat app. My app pulls message details from Slack and displays a onebox.

Comment: Slack replied on Twitter: "If the link is the only thing you have to work with, you're doing it the best way already!"  https://twitter.com/SlackAPI/status/911258119099092992

Comment: Well, looks like you good to go then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Im new in python, but i got same problem when i creating SlackBot (by SlackBolt), and i solved it like that:

```
link = 'https://***.slack.com/archives/C03UGEVQ6BX/p1668769293636169'

#Grab information from link

wrong_link_list = link.split('/')
wrong_ts = wrong_link_list[-1]
t_ts = wrong_ts.replace('p', '', 1)
dot = '.'
char_count = 10

#Put information in variables

channel = wrong_link_list[-2]
text = 'Hey dude!'
mess_ts = t_ts[:char_count] + dot + t_ts[char_count:]

app.client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel, text=text, thread_ts = mess_ts)
```

Hope this will help you!